# URL.py in Django unexpected behaviour

Tags: django, url, apache2, mod-wsgi, configuration-files

I've configured url.py as is explained in different places of the Django documentation, but its behaviour is completely anomalous, between consecutives acceses. In Debug Mode and after looking for an url I get the "Page not found" error. The strange thing is that between acceses the error given is different:

```
... Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/?$
    ^cheqsim/?$
    ^login/?$
    ^logout/?$
    ^questions/?$
```

But if I look at url.py my last element is ^searchquestions/?$ and I had restarted the server before looking at it, but the error is indicating me a different urlpattern from the actual in url.py.

Then I keep looking URLs and when I delete all the cookies and I try some non-existent URL I get the actual URL.py:

```
, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^login/?$
    ^logout/?$
    ^admin/?$
    ^cheqsim/?$
    ^searchquestions/?$
```

Ok, so now I try http://mysite.com/myprojecturl/searchquestions/ and voila! It appears a new pattern error that leave me completely knock out:

```
, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^admin/?$
    ^cheqsim/?$
    ^login/?$
    ^logout/?$
```

A pattern that I had used like 5 or 6 hours ago!!!

Please, do anybody have any idea of what is happening to me because this is really frustrating...

Thank you very much

P.S.: By the way, some URLs matches sometimes magicly

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have multiple runserver instances running.
2. Check the [ROOT_URLCONF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-ROOT_URLCONF) setting

Comment: Thanks Rahul but I had already check those two issues:

**1** in the console "ps -A" and I didn't get any python process when I closed the runserver (with Ctrl+C). If I run again and look for processes I see two instances (I suppose is normal).

**2** ROOT_URLCONF is well configured, but I'm afraid of what it says in the documentation: `Can be overridden on a per-request basis by setting the attribute urlconf on the incoming HttpRequest` But I doubt this is happening without setting that parameter explictely... What do you think? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It seems the solution is changing the project.wsgi file and is well explained here: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

Anyway only time will know... xD